# Array items are not appending to the HTML Table tbody with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is formatted and I want the contents of my array to be displayed in them, but nothing is displayed when I load my web page. It seems to not be adding anything to the tbody id that I have created in my html code. Here is my code that I have.

```
    var Movie = function (movieTitle, movieYear, length, format, rating, favorite) {
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
        this.movieYear = movieYear;
        this.length = length;
        this.format = format;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.favorite = favorite;
    };

    var movies = new Array();
    movies[0] = new Movie("Hangover", 2009, 210, "Dvd", 4, "Yes");
    movies[1] = new Movie("Taken", 2008, 200, "BluRay", 5, "Yes");
    movies[2] = new Movie("Avengers", 2011, 242, "Cloud", 3, "No");
    movies[3] = new Movie("Iron Man", 2010, 311, "Computer", 4, "Yes");
    movies[4] = new Movie("Rounders", 1990, 252, "Dvd", 5, "Yes");
    movies[5] = new Movie("42", 2013, 202, "BluRay", 4, "No");
    movies[6] = new Movie("Water Boy", 1988, 211, "Dvd", 5, "Yes");
    movies[7] = new Movie("21", 2010, 192, "Cloud", 3, "No");
    movies[8] = new Movie("I am Legend", 2009, "Computer", 5, "Yes");
    movies[9] = new Movie("Titanic", 1997, 320, "Dvd", 2, "No");

    $("#add").click(function(event){

        var movie = new Movie(
            $("#movieTitle").val(),
            $("#movieYear").val(),
            $("#lengthInMins").val(),
            $("#formatSelections").val(),
            $("#ratingSelections").val(),
            $("#favoriteSelction").val()
            );

        movies[movies.length] = movie;

        updateTableData();
        $("#formMovieData").hide(500, function() {
              $("#showMovies").show();
        });

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the defualt anchor actions
    });

    function updateTableData() {
        //$("#movieData").empty();
        var tbody = $("#movieData");

        for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
            var id = i + "_" + movies[i]["movieTitle"];
            var tr = "<tr>";
            for (var key in movies[i]) {
                tr += "<td>" + movies[i][key] + "</td>";
            }

            tr += "<td><a id='" + id + "' href='#'" + "> Edit </a></td>";
            tr += "<td><a id='" + id + "' href='#'" + "> Delete </a></td>";
            tr += "</tr>";
            tbody.append(tr);

            $("#" + id).click(function () {
                var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
                var idx = elementId.indexOf("_");
                var index = parseInt(elementId.substr(0, idx));
                $("#movieTitle").val(movies[index].movieTitle);
                $("#movieYear").val(movies[index].movieYear);
                $("#lengthInMins").val(movies[index].length);
                $("#formatSelections").val(movies[index].format);
                $("#ratingSelections").val(movies[index].rating);
                $("#favoriteSelection").val(movies[index].favorite);

                $("#showMovies").hide(500, function() {
                        $("#formMovieData").show();
                  });
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my html code I have hard coded some items that I want to show in my tables also I have the ability to add a new one as well. I am working on the process to add or delete the information as well, but I need to show items first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homework 3</title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header><h1 class="bg-primary">The Movie Collection</h1></header>

    <nav id="navigation" class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-default">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Movie Options
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a id="addMovieDataCmd" href="#">Add New Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a id="showMoviesCmd" href="#">Show All Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a id="browseNewMoviesCmd" href="http://www.fandango.com/new-dvd-releases">Browse New Release Movies</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="mainContent" class="col-sm-9">
        <form id="formMovieData" class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Add New Movie</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="movieTitle" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Movie Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                        <input id="movieTitle" name="movieTitle" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="movieYear" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Year of Movie</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                        <input id="movieYear" name="movieYear" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lengthInMins" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Length In Minutes</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                        <input id="lengthInMins" name="lengthInMins" type="number" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="format" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Format</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                        <select id="formatSelections" name="selections" class="form-control">
                            <option>Dvd</option>
                            <option>BluRay</option>
                            <option>Computer</option>
                            <option>Cloud</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rating" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Rating</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                        <select id="ratingSelections" name="selections2" class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option selected>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="favorites" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Favorite</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
                        <select id="favoriteSelection" name="selections3" class="form-control">
                            <option>Yes</option>
                            <option>No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
                        <input id="clear" name="clear" type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" />enter code here
                        <input id="add" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <div id="showMovies">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>List of Movies</legend>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Movie Id</th>
                            <th>Movie Title</th>
                            <th>Movie Year</th>
                            <th>Movie Length</th>
                            <th>Movie Format</th>
                            <th>Movie Rating</th>
                            <th>Favorite Movie</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="movieData">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/homework3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay I just shared my html code as well.

Comment: where is the method hideshow?

Comment: I didn't have a method for the hideShow(). I was thinking that was a method with jQuery. Similar to the hide().

Comment: I took out the hideShows because I could not find anything that it was a method with jQuery. I replaced it with this:
$("#showMovies").hide(500, function(){
       $("#formMovieData").show();
});

Comment: start with http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GbML5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to call function `updateTableData()` when loading page:

Make sure you are doing it by:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateTableData();
});
```

Also, your button shouldn't be `submit` type in order to not submit form, just throw Javascript events:

```
<input id="add" name="submit" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Finally, there's a method call to a non existant function:

```
hideshow("#formMovieData", 500, "#showMovies", 500);
```

You can just remove it from code. (I'm not seeing any advantage in using some hide/show effect on click "Add")

[See an example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLtks/1)

Comment: This worked great, but I had to put the updateTableData(); after I declared the movies array. Thank you so much for your help.